# How does Akka messaging work

Tags: akka

I don't have any Akka experience at all. I would like to know how Akka messaging work within JVM and also between JVMs.

- Are messages within JVM some POJO like objects?
- Is there any sort of JMS like server needed for inter JVM communication?
- How does Akka abstract differences between these two types of messages?
- Is serialization needed?
- Can I use some other protocols (e.g. JMS, SOAP, ...) for inter JVM communication? For example Spring Integration or Apache Camel can handle any type of communication protocol.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most of these questions are answered in the section on remoting in the documentation:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.6/scala/remoting.html

- Messages within a JVM are whatever you want them to be so long as they are immutable.
- Nothing is needed beyond two `ActorSystems` set up for remoting that can reach each other over the network.  Akka does not use JMS.
- Akka provides location transparency, the difference between local and remote communication is hidden from the user (that is, the end developer).  See this section on location transparency: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.6/general/remoting.html
- Yes.  See the serialization section of the first link in this answer.
- Akka can use ZeroMQ for remote communication between actors. Camel integration is available but not for inter-actor communication, it can be used to integrate other protocols using actors as producers or consumers.